# Does AS3 have a similar class to Java's NumberFormat

Tags: java, apache-flex, actionscript-3, number-formatting, pad

I have always used the NumberFormat class in Java to do simple number padding ie. turn 1, 2, 3... into 0001, 0002, 0003....

Is there a similar utility in ActionScript to do my padding, or will I have to write a custom function?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Seems there is nothing built in. This will do it:

```
function padZero (num:Number, digits:int):String {
  var ret:String = num.toString();
  while (ret.length < digits)
    ret = "0" + ret;
  return ret;
}
```

Though [com.adobe.utils.NumberFormatter](http://weblogs.macromedia.com/as_libraries/docs/corelib/com/adobe/utils/NumberFormatter.html) has `addLeadingZero(n:Number):String`, which sounds promising, but according to the spec it pads a single zero to numbers between -1 and 10. I guess the function is useful for time output only.

Answer (score 1):

Flash now has the NumberFormatter() class as part of flash.globalization.*

it will format numbers in the users locale

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/beta/reference/actionscript/3/flash/globalization/NumberFormatter.html

you can also set the number of leading, or trailing zeros

Comment: Thanks for updating this!  Since this question is also a Flex question, it's worth noting that there is also a [spark.formatters.NumberFormatter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/spark/formatters/NumberFormatter.html), which wraps the class you referenced and also provides fallback support for those OS's that don't support the `flash.globalization.NumberFormatter` methods.